# What is the most expensive project related to Earth's geology and/or to engineering geology on the Earth?

Tags: geology, economic-geology, world-building, energy

Costs related to space exploration are well documented. 
However, what about the costs of Earth projects like dam/mines/tunnels? 
What has been the most expensive projects? I know that nuclear power plants construction costs may reach the 10 billions of dollars/eur, but what about other projects?

As an example, how much did cost to set up the Ghawar oil field in Saudi Arabia?
 How expensive was the South Deep gold mine in South Africa?

My question is triggered by the expected costs related to deep geological disposal of radioactive waste, it should be on the order of 50/100 billions USD/EUR, so I would like to compare apples and oranges to understand how credible is that estimate.

Comment: That's economy, only partly earth science. To get an answer you must define "cost" because it's just a slogan. Do you mean only exploration and construction, that's trivial ? But a lot of "cost" is not accounted for or ignored, especially all those positions of second order like environmental destruction, loss of biologically active area, loss of diversity, greenhouse gas release of construction work, relocating people and tensions growing from that, etc. If you include that, "cost" grows towards infinity.

Comment: The reason why the process can only be kept up by infinitely providing money, otherwise it wouldn't work anyway. But that's a completely irrelevant thing here. From a mere geoscience point oif view, a safe "deep geoligal disposal of radioactive waste" does not exist, you can only put it out of sight for a while. Voting to close as too unspecific, but the answer is "undefined" or "infinite" in terms of money.

Comment: I agree with @ebv, the question is too broad and more economical than geological. Plus you have to consider one thing: most projects (tunnels, dams, mines, oil fields...) actually make more money than what they have cost, it's why they were built in the first place.

Comment: [Crossrail](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/nov/08/crossrail-faces-further-delays-and-will-cost-more-than-18bn-tfl) is up to £18 billion by now (I guess they mean the "small" billions)...

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival It does not matter that they make money: they costed. How they were funded (profit? selling jewels? stealing money from old people?) is not the point of my question.

Comment: @a_donda do not be offuscated from your political or personal point of view. Deep geological disposal is being planned and/or performed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onkalo_spent_nuclear_fuel_repository "The estimated cost of this project is about €818 million" or the swiss case https://www.bfe.admin.ch/bfe/en/home/supply/nuclear-energy/radioactive-waste/waste-disposal-principles/deep-geological-repositories.html (they estimate 20-50 bilions EUR)

Comment: @a_donda when we mention that the mission to the Moon costed 1 bilion (I don't knwo, random number) do we take into account the CO2eq emitted in the higher layer of the stratosphere? the contaminants being released at the launch of the Saturn V? no, so why should we take into account them here? only because it is tangible?

Comment: Well, but here's geoscience. We "believe in" peer reviewed publications that focus on a specific question or scenario and that are as independent as possible. I am sure you can find enough information on the subject deep drilling to put the waste under the carpet.

Comment: @a_donda ?Do you mean that the research on the deep geological disposal of waste are not peer-reviewed research?
Have a look at the following peer reviewed researchs:
https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2018WR024218 (authors from Cambridge, UK, year 2019)
this chapter from a book summing up >2 decades of peer-reviewed res
https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118877517.ch2 (2015, authors from Berkeley Lab in the US and Imperial College London, UK)
Or (France, >100 peer-reviewed citations):
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00603-012-0339-6

Comment: That goes in the right direction :-)

Comment: the largest and most expensive geology related project is the coal and oil industry.